# DNS servers for a website hosted on Microsoft Azure

Tags: networking, dns, azure, hosting, web-hosting

If my website is hosted on Microsoft Auzre, should Microsoft give me some DNS servers or I should find my own DNS servers?
Could I use Google's DNS servers - 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4?

Comment: Whatever registrar you purchased the domain name will offer DNS services as part of the deal, use it.

Comment: Google won't know about your domain unless you publish that information.  Whom ever is your register is, that is whom should be publishing that information, there isn't a single way to approach this problem.  How are you approaching the problem of broadcasting that information, is how you approach the problem, you have to tell us in other words.

Comment: Are you asking which DNS servers your VMs in Azure should use to resolve DNS queries or which servers should be used to serve DNS requests for your website/domain?

Comment: I am asking about which servers should be used to serve DNS requests for my website!

Answer (score 0):

You register a domain name with a service provider (A). There you should configure the DNS. In some cases it's better to change the DNS to another provider (B). In that case you need to change the nameservers, after which the (worldwide) DNS system use B to lookup the DNS. This is used by Google and other DNS providers like OpenDNS.

Google's and Openprovider's DNS servers are for clients, like your laptop. Don't confuse the two.